# How to select by category name with WordPress query

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a website with 3 post_type and I have 2 items in categories
Videos (name post_type='video')
Articles (name post_type =
'article')
News (name post_type = 'post')

---

Categories
Spain
Portugal

Next we ask you to develop these queries
Write the wordpress “query” to show
All Videos and News from Spain
2. Returns the loop showing the Featured Image of the post in its thumbnail version; the Title and Abstract
Write the wordpress “query” to show
the first 3 Articles of Portugal
Returns the Loop showing first the Category of the post and the Title of the post

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should create the category name before you try to choose it from the list

Comment: Spain and Portugal are two categories.

Comment: Please be more specific and write the code for that.